# How to compile/package and load an extension with Xerial JDBC Sqlite library?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I am using Xerial sqlite [JDBC](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) library in my Java application and need to add [memstat](https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/memstat.c) extension so that I can track heap usage of Sqlite.
I do not have great knowledge of C++.
I want to know how can I statically link the extension with sqlite so file and load it at runtime in my Java app